# Simple Java mistake

Tags: java

```
package e.power.bhd;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EPowerBhd {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int accountNum = 1;
    double cMeter;
    double pMeter;
    double eUsage;
    double totalDueAmount = 0.0;
    double Tot = 0.0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (accountNum != 0) {

            // user enter account no
            System.out.print("Enter Account number (0 to stop ) : ");
            accountNum = input.nextInt();
            // user enter current meter reading
            System.out.print("Current meter reading : ");
            cMeter = input.nextDouble();
            // user enter previous meter reading
            System.out.print("Previous meter reading : ");
            pMeter = input.nextDouble();
            eUsage = cMeter - pMeter;
            System.out.print("Electricity Usage(in kWh) : " + eUsage);
            System.out.println();

            if (eUsage >= 1 && eUsage <= 200) {
                totalDueAmount = 0.218 * eUsage;
            } else if (eUsage > 200 && eUsage <= 300) {
                totalDueAmount = 0.334 * eUsage;
            } else if (eUsage > 300 && eUsage <= 600) {
                totalDueAmount = 0.516 * eUsage;
            } else if (eUsage > 600 && eUsage <= 900) {
                totalDueAmount = 0.546 * eUsage;
            } else {
                totalDueAmount = 0.571 * eUsage;
            }
            System.out.println();  // total amount for the account is displayed
            System.out.println("Amount number : " + accountNum + "," + " your charge is " + "RM" + totalDueAmount);
            Tot = totalDueAmount++;
            System.out.println();

        } // loop exit and displa the total amount for all accounts
        System.out.println("Total Amount collected  = " + "RM" + Tot);
        System.out.println("________________________________");
        System.out.println("--- DONE ----");
        System.out.println("________________________________");

    }

}
```

I have completed a java program in which  the user enter account number, current meter reading and previous current reading and then calculates electricity usag 
It will calculate electricity usage for accounts until user terminates the loop by entering 0 and  the total for all accounts are calculated  and displayed.

In this program if user enter 0 at first it should show
"No account has been processed." only   and  terminates.

Attached is the program code and detail of the program.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/85mm1w09tl7c1n3/1.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8w0ngjt9em70q7w/2.png?dl=0

Any help is mostly appreciated..

Comment: And what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: We really aren't able to give you a proper answer if such question don't exist. It'll just make your post be prone to be flagged as too broad.

Comment: You say what it should do, yet you don't have any code to handle the case you presented. Maybe you should do that first?

Comment: Hint: `if (accountNum == 0 && Tot == 0.0) { // print your message and break; out of loop }`. You should do this inside the `while` loop and right after you collect the `accountNum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Lacks Conditional Statement

**The answer to the mistake in your program is that it's an unending loop. It'll always be true because you just asked the value of `accountNum` and didn't add conditional statement.**

Use this code below as replacement to your code and it works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Yehey {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int accountNum = 1;
        double cMeter;
        double pMeter;
        double eUsage;
        double totalDueAmount = 0.0;
        double Tot = 0.0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {

            // user enter account no
            System.out.print("Enter Account number (0 to stop ) : ");
            accountNum = input.nextInt();
            if (accountNum==1) {
                // user enter current meter reading
                System.out.print("Current meter reading : ");
                cMeter = input.nextDouble();
                // user enter previous meter reading
                System.out.print("Previous meter reading : ");
                pMeter = input.nextDouble();
                eUsage = cMeter - pMeter;
                System.out.print("Electricity Usage(in kWh) : " + eUsage);
                System.out.println();

                if (eUsage >= 1 && eUsage <= 200) {
                    totalDueAmount = 0.218 * eUsage;
                } else if (eUsage > 200 && eUsage <= 300) {
                    totalDueAmount = 0.334 * eUsage;
                } else if (eUsage > 300 && eUsage <= 600) {
                    totalDueAmount = 0.516 * eUsage;
                } else if (eUsage > 600 && eUsage <= 900) {
                    totalDueAmount = 0.546 * eUsage;
                } else {
                    totalDueAmount = 0.571 * eUsage;
                }
                System.out.println();  // total amount for the account is displayed
                System.out.println("Amount number : " + accountNum + "," + " your charge is " + "RM" + totalDueAmount);
                Tot = totalDueAmount++;
                System.out.println();

                // loop exit and displa the total amount for all accounts
                System.out.println("Total Amount collected  = " + "RM" + Tot);
                System.out.println("________________________________");
                System.out.println("--- DONE ----");
                System.out.println("________________________________");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using my program.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Added changes:
1. Changed the inside condition of while to `true`
2. Added if statement to execute code if accountNum remains 1 and breaks the program if its value changed to other values.
3. Added...`System.out.println("Thank you for using my program."); break;` if the value of accountNum is not equal to zero

*(Note: Please clarify what your problem or question is to avoid having your question be flagged or have down votes.)*

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do it.

1. Using the `continue` keyword. Watch below.

   ```
   while (accountNum != 0) {
       // user enter account no
       System.out.print("Enter Account number (0 to stop ) : ");
       accountNum = input.nextInt()
       if(accountNum==0){
            continue;
       }
       // user enter current meter reading
       System.out.print("Current meter reading : ");
       cMeter = input.nextDouble();

   //rest of your code
   ```
2. Using the `Sytem.exit(-1)`

   ```
   while (accountNum != 0) {
       // user enter account no
       System.out.print("Enter Account number (0 to stop ) : ");
       accountNum = input.nextInt()
       if(accountNum==0){
            System.exit(-1);
       }
       // user enter current meter reading
       System.out.print("Current meter reading : ");
       cMeter = input.nextDouble();
       //rest of your code
   ```